# Excel VBA loop Insert row based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, row

I have tried a lot to get a loop to do this, but i can't seem to get it to work. Anyone have an idea I can try, this works but it is very messy code?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range

Set KeyCells = Range("D2")

Range("D3:D23").ClearContents

If Range("D25").Value >= 2 Then Range("D3").Value = Range("D2").Value + 1
If Range("D25").Value >= 3 Then Range("D4").Value = Range("D3").Value + 1
If Range("D25").Value >= 4 Then Range("D5").Value = Range("D4").Value + 1
If Range("D25").Value >= 5 Then Range("D6").Value = Range("D5").Value + 1
If Range("D25").Value >= 6 Then Range("D7").Value = Range("D6").Value + 1
If Range("D25").Value >= 7 Then Range("D8").Value = Range("D7").Value + 1
If Range("D25").Value >= 8 Then Range("D9").Value = Range("D8").Value + 1
If Range("D25").Value >= 9 Then Range("D10").Value = Range("D9").Value + 1
If Range("D25").Value >= 10 Then Range("D11").Value = Range("D10").Value + 1
If Range("D25").Value >= 11 Then Range("D12").Value = Range("D11").Value + 1
If Range("D25").Value >= 12 Then Range("D13").Value = Range("D12").Value + 1
If Range("D25").Value >= 13 Then Range("D14").Value = Range("D13").Value + 1
If Range("D25").Value >= 14 Then Range("D15").Value = Range("D14").Value + 1
If Range("D25").Value >= 15 Then Range("D16").Value = Range("D15").Value + 1
If Range("D25").Value >= 16 Then Range("D17").Value = Range("D16").Value + 1
If Range("D25").Value >= 17 Then Range("D18").Value = Range("D17").Value + 1
If Range("D25").Value >= 18 Then Range("D19").Value = Range("D18").Value + 1
If Range("D25").Value >= 19 Then Range("D20").Value = Range("D19").Value + 1
If Range("D25").Value >= 20 Then Range("D21").Value = Range("D20").Value + 1
If Range("D25").Value >= 21 Then Range("D22").Value = Range("D21").Value + 1
If Range("D25").Value >= 22 Then Range("D23").Value = Range("D22").Value + 1

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What does "can't get it to work" mean ? For one thing this will trigger an infinite loop. Should it be triggered when D2 is changed or D25 is changed?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: When i type an int in "D2", it corresponds with an int in "D25". If the int in "D25" is larger than 1, another cell shuold be created in "D3+" with the int from "D2" +1 for every time. That's why i thought about loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the problem with the change event (that seems to be another question and a search on this site will give you the answers you need). You need to look at the patterns of your logic.

Assuming that `D25` can only be an integer between 2 and 22, inclusively, try:

```
Dim i as long
For i = 2 to Range("D25").Value
    Range("D" & i + 1).Value = Range("D" & i).Value + 1
Next i
```

That said, as @W-hit said, it would be useful to know what you are trying to accomplish as we may well be facing an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here

Comment: I don't have a problem with the change event, that works like a charm. But this did absolutely what i wantet to accomplish, much cleaner than the temp-solution i created. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Without loop (not tested):

```
...
If Range("D25").Value >= 2 Then
    Range("D3").Resize(Int(Range("D25").Value) - 1).Formula = "=D$2 + (ROW() - 2)"
End If
```

Comment: Actually this also did exactly what i were looking for. I just made it to a much bigger problem in my head. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer solved your question then you may consider marking it as accepted. Thank you